# How did they come up with joint PDF representation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, bayesian

I am looking at this problem, and get it up to the calculation of the joint PDF, which is 1/12.  From that point, I do not get how they achieve the parallelogram.  Could someone please tell me?  Thank you.

[image: pdf]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u4L2oq1p40&t=187).

From the inequality $\theta - 1 \leq x \leq \theta + 1$, two equations are obtained:

$\theta \leq x + 1$, and

$\theta \geq x - 1$.

Plot them on the $\theta$ vs $x$ plane, we got the shown graph.

[image: exp]

The conditional expectation $\mathbf E[\Theta\mid X=x]$ of the uniformly distributed $\Theta$ is just the midpoint of that uniform distribution.  This explain the plot of $\mathbf E[\Theta\mid X=x]$ inside the parallelogram.